# How do I determine the settings for leaflet::setView() from an existing map?

Tags: r, leaflet

When building a new map with leaflet in R (working in RStudio), I'm using `setView()` to set the initial map center and zoom level. I understand the function's syntax and with a bunch of trial and error, can get pretty close to what I want. Something like:

```
library(leaflet); library(magrittr)

leaflet::breweries91 %>% 
    leaflet() %>% 
    # see what breweries are close to Ingolstadt 
    # without putting it or anything else in the center of the frame
    setView(11, 49,  zoom = 9) %>% 
    addTiles() %>% 
    addMarkers()
```

I came at the `setView()` arguments above by zooming the map around to what I liked, then testing coordinates and zoom levels until I got something close to what I arrived at with my mouse.

I'd prefer to be able to set an existing map to the settings I like, then somehow retrieve the current pan/zoom settings from that map and use those settings in my `setView()` function.

Is there a way to retrieve those settings from an existing map that I've zoomed/panned? I'm less interested in arriving at the "right" settings programmatically and more interested in bridging the gap between "I clicked around a bit and found something I like" vs. "I coded in some coordinates".

To be clear, I'm sure there's a way to average distances, write a centering function, or [determine initial `setView()` settings based on the data like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406598/leaflet-in-r-setview-based-on-range-of-latitude-and-longitude-from-dataset), but I'm specifically asking about getting map user data, rather than calculating something, mostly because I often don't know what I want to display as the center of the map until I've created an initial version and have explored the data in the map itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**mapview** has a function called `addMouseCoordinates` which will render a little strip at the top of your map displaying details about mouse cursor position (incl. zoom). With this you can simply pan/zoom the map to the position you like, put the cursor at the center of the map and use the displayed coordinates and zoom level to construct `setView` for your final map.

```
library(mapview) # loads leaflet automatically

breweries91 %>% 
  leaflet() %>% 
  # see what breweries are close to Ingolstadt 
  # without putting it or anything else in the center of the frame
  setView(11, 49,  zoom = 9) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers() %>%
  addMouseCoordinates(style = "basic")

# or for the initial scanning simply
mapview(breweries91)
```